# Look past shoulder

Tags: idioms

A friend’s coworker invited him to lunch via email and in the email he also wrote the below.

if no, please look past my shoulder when you see me next time

What does the “look past shoulder” mean? Ignore me (sarcasm?)

Comment: "Put out the fire and don't look past my shoulder" Baba O'Riley,
The Who

Comment: "And don't look past my shoulder, Reggie! Reggie! Reggie!" Summer of Sam, https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=summer-of-sam - referencing The Who

Comment: "look past" by itself is a synonym for "ignore". https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/ignore

Comment: Is the coworker a native English speaker, and if so, what country is he from? (And, for that matter, what country are they in now?)

Comment: I’m not sure if the coworker is a native speaker. Both are in Japan.

Answer (score 1):

from google books:

> to **look past** or by without seeing, hence to refrain from bestowing
>   notice or attention upon  [Webster's Collegiate Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=4aEMAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22look%20past%22%20dictionary&pg=PA583#v=onepage&q=%22look%20past%22%20dictionary&f=false)

As in:

> ... if no, please ignore me when you see me next time!

As for the *shoulder* reference ... my guess here is to not even make eye contact.

Comment: But why "look past my shoulder" rather than "look past me"?

Comment: @lbf:  Might the person be alluding to his giving the OP the cold shoulder?

Comment: @Wordster indeed!

Answer (score 1):

"Don't look past me" can mean "Don't ignore me", since "look past" can mean (amongst other things) ignore/snub [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/ignore). So the phrase "Don't look past my shoulder" makes sense as "Don't ignore me".

Searching Google and Google Books in tight date ranges, the first mention of the exact phrase "look past my shoulder" is from the song Baba O'Riley by the [The Who](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baba_O%27Riley) 1971.